# Generating survival times in days or in years

Tags: survival, hazard, units

When generating survival times to simulate Cox proportional hazards models, does it matter to generate them in days or in years?

In theory, I guess it does not matter. But in practice? Is there a preference regarding computational issues?

Thank you!
Marco

Comment: There are no computational issues.  Choose a time unit that is readily interpretable.

Comment: I believe it's advantageous to avoid ties when dealing with time as a continuous variable.  Therefore I think you'd want to base your results on the finest-grained measurements you can get (if that is part of what your question implies).

Comment: @Whuber: Ok Ok, thanks!
@rolanda2: Yes, you are right. But if I generate survival times in years I keep all decimal points. Thx

Comment: @whuber, @rolando2 Make answers of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no computational issues behind using a different time scale. I would make sure the time scale you used is biologically/practically meaningful and plausible to collect. If you're talking about the time-to-failure of a single node in a computer cluster, you might be able to say you'd know the event time down to a fraction of a second. If you're talking about time until HIV seroconversion, you'd be lucky to know the day, and more likely know the week or month. Simulation studies are most useful when they're conducted similarly.

I wouldn't worry to much about ties in your time - they'll happen in real-life too, and its useful for your situation to know how to handle them.

So I'd say, generally, pick a good, interpretable time scale, and retain as much precision as *is reasonable in a real-world setting*.